# My updater script for portable apps works. But not for VSCode

Tags: powershell, 7-zip, visual-studio-code, portable, portable-apps

### Edit: Fixed version below.

I have a script that lets me update any app that is distributed in portable format, and it works. With the exception of VSCode. With VSCode, after running the script, I'm always on the same version as before. Here's the specific script for XnViewMP, which works 100%:

```
$project = "XnViewMP"
$url = "https://download.xnview.com/XnViewMP-win-x64.zip"
Set-Location \PortableApps\$project

Write-Output `n`n"Trying to get file from:" $url

try {mkdir .staging -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'} catch{}

Set-Location .staging
curl.exe $url -L -o $project'.zip'
7z x -aoa -spe $project'.zip'
Remove-Item $project'.zip'

Get-ChildItem -Path ".\*" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination ..\ -Force -Confirm:$False
Get-ChildItem -Path ".\*" -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse

Set-Location \PortableApps\$project
Remove-Item .staging -Recurse
```

Pretty simple as these things go. Make a staging folder, download an archive via cURL, extract the archive, then put the extracted contents into the app's actual folder.
But for VSCode, this fails somewhere. While some files are updated, like Code.exe, which has the new version number, VSCode still shows the old version number and asks me to update.
Only the first two lines are different for the VSCode version:

```
$project = "VSCode"
$url = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkid=850641"
```

Extracting and overwriting with 7z GUI works fine. But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in Powershell.

Feel free to use this script for yourself, by the way.

Comment: Have you followed the additional instructions in [Portable Mode in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable)?

Comment: Yes, I have indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, well. Somehow I always find the answer just after posting to the web.
Apparently, that copy operation I had flattens the directory structure, breaking some apps, but not others.
Here's the full, fixed script:

```
$project = "VSCode"
$url = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkid=850641"
Set-Location \PortableApps\$project

Write-Output `n`n"Trying to get file from:" $url

try {mkdir .staging -erroraction 'silentlycontinue'} catch{}

Set-Location .staging
curl.exe $url -L -o $project'.zip'
7z x -aoa -spe $project'.zip'
Remove-Item $project'.zip'
# The part below is new and fixed:
Copy-Item .\* -Destination ..\ -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$False
Remove-Item .\* -Recurse -Force

Set-Location \PortableApps\$project
Remove-Item .staging -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: One thing that's left to do here is to 'merge' .staging with the $project folder (avoiding the unnecessary copy operation)